# Ubuntu 18.04 orange icons coloured grey

Tags: 18.04, icons

When I open my Ubuntu 18.04, some app and folder icons are coloured grey. I don't mean greyed-out but covered with a dark grey overlay. (I can see a little orange peeking out on the tops.) It's not just the desktop icons, but much of what is usually orange (e.g. the software updates progress bars). I recently tried unsuccessfully to install or enable some apps in the terminal, not knowing what I was doing or what I have done. (I usually get help with this stuff from people much more knowledgeable than me, but am lately on my own.) Not knowing what I did, I don't know if it's a good idea to just move to trash those apps on the desktop it seems I won't be using (like ARChon Packager Manager and android-studio), but the 'home' folder I put on the desktop and have been using has the same appearance. So far, everything seems to function as usual, but I'm concerned I'm being told something I should know that I don't understand. Is there something wrong here that should be attended to? (I hope I don't have to go back in the terminal and use commands to reverse my mistakes.) Or should I just ignore it as long as there's no apparent problem?
Add edit: On viewing related posts, I see something similar related to symbolic icons and running applications. I don't know what those terms mean, but I do remember something I tried to add having the word 'runtime'. Could this be what I'm seeing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just the new theme of the Yaru icons theme. (You may have installed communitheme). Your system is just updated to use the new theme.

https://www.linuxuprising.com/2020/01/new-folder-icons-aubergine-as-second.html